# What do you call a house with a yard?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word in English, no matter from which origin e.g. French, Latin, etc., to describe a house that has a yard area? Or do we just have to say *house/home with a yard*?
**Update**: By house, I mean an average apartment (flat) with bedrooms, sitting room, bathroom and a kitchen. I am, however, not sure if that's the way *house* is used colloquially. In fact I am translating a non-English text that reads "houses with yards" into English. That's why I came up with the question.
**Update 2**:  In response to @mitch, text of origin is [in Persian]: 
اگرچه **خانه های حیاط دار** از نظر اقلیمی هنوز در بسیاری از نقاط دنیا قابل قبول اند، ولی در حال تبدیل به اشکال دیگری هستند.

And Google Translate gives:
The **courtyard houses** of the climate in many parts of the world have been acceptable, but are converted into other forms.

As in Google's sentence *courtyard house* seems reasonable. Doesn't it?

Comment: "House and yard".  Usually if there is no yard, though, some other term is used.

Comment: That's like asking for a word that means a house with a kitchen or a house with a bathroom: you wouldn't have one because that's the normal arrangement.

Comment: I'm not sure if _curtilage_ is accepted as a verb yet, but if so you could refer to a curtilaged house.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'curtilaged' sounds like it has been sent to the vet to have its ears and tail bobbed.

Comment: Mehdi, what is the term you're translating, and what does google translate give you (that will give us a start).

Comment: Your update doesn't really make things clearer. An apartment is a ‘house’ in a multi-storey building; it implies there being _more_ apartments in the same building, usually on different floors. A yard, by contrast, is by definition on the _ground_, and the only apartments that can have yards are ground-floor apartments (and even they usually don't).

Comment: I would take a *"courtyard house" to be a house which has an interior courtyard (so it is surrounded on three or four sides by the house).

Comment: @janus you're right i'd better use building instead if an apartment as I do not mean an apartment in the sense you mentioned.

Comment: A building that comprises just one unit of residence and has a bedroom, bathroom, sitting room, kitchen, and garden would normally and most generically just be called a ***house***. Depending on various details, there may be a more precise term, but that description exactly fits the mental image conjured up by the word _house_ on its own.

Comment: You can -- well, or should -- never use *house* to mean an apartment/flat. Those are two VERY different things in English! Herein seems to lie your error. And while things like *condominium* and *duplex* also exist, these too are different.

Answer (score 3):

This depends a lot on where you are. In North America, it's assumed that a house is free-standing and has a yard.

In the UK, however, I don't think that's necessarily the case, since I've been told that "house" means row-house.

Comment: Actually we generally call free-standing houses "detached houses".

Comment: Row houses usually do have a yard, too, albeit a smaller one (for obvious reasons of geometry).

Comment: In the UK, "house" is completely unspecific as to whether it is detached (free-standing), semi-detached (one of a pair of joined houses) or terraced (one of a row of joined houses) - you would usually need to specify which, if it is important. "House" never in my experience means "flat" or "apartment". Only unusually large, wealthy houses have enclosed courtyards, but most houses have at least a little bit of garden at the front or back or both (and it is usually called a garden rather than a yard even if it is completely paved). There is no special word for a house with or without a garden.

Comment: In the UK, 'yard' is very distinct from 'garden' - 'yard' suggests a small paved/hard-surfaced area at the back of the house with space for rubbish bins etc, while 'garden' implies a larger area with lawn and/or plants etc. @Colin Fine In my experience, a yard is only called a garden by estate agents. . .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a cultural/architectural thing which is, one might say, untranslatable in the way you want.

In Modern European architecture, most family homes ('houses') do not include a courtyard. In fact they are very rare. Also, houses that do have courtyards do not have a special name for such a house, they are simply houses with courtyards. Such a house is remarkable for its uncommonness, but is not considered a concept on its own.

It seems you are looking for a *single* English word for this concept. I note that the Persian for this concept, خانه های حیاط, ( khaneh hayeh heeyat), is most literally three words, 'house', 'with', and 'yard'. So even in Persian culture, where houses very commonly have courtyards (an interior yard), it takes three words. As extensive as English vocabulary is, there is no necessity that every concept possible has a single word for it, moreso when there's hardly a cultural pattern for it.

Comment: In fact I was looking for equivalent for "خانه های حیاط دار". _Agarcheh_ means _although_

Comment: This raises an important point: are we actually talking about _courtyards_ (as the Google Translate translation would indicate), or just general _yards_, i.e., basically just gardens (as in the question itself)?

Comment: @MehdiHaghgoo oops, my google-fu isn't that good. So my assumption was totally wrong then, you don't care about a house with a courtyard, but rather a house that has a yard in front. But despite my mistake, everything else still holds even with that new wording. Also, what Maria says is appropriate, a house, in cultures associated with English speakers, usually by default has a yard with it.